# Is there way to get to "Blackbox" project lab without Repair skill?

Tags: prey

There is quest to get into Blackbox project lab in Hardware labs in Prey (2017). But there is breach near entrance to lab, and to seal it, you need to repair control panel of door, which leads to breach. And it requires Repair skill lvl2.

I'm currently on "typhon-only skills" playthrough, so I don't have, and will not have this skill. Is there any other way to seal breach, so I can get into lab?

Comment: I thought it out, and I couldn't see a way. Ended up upgrading my repair skill to get in.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  You can jump on top of the Recycler Charge chamber in the lab below it.  If you have Mimic turn into something small and slip through the opening.